# MYSQL - Select one of many ranges as one row in one statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a range of data which i am trying to reduce.

I would like to select all the data to have distinct ranges

Example (Date Time)

```
01/01/2017 01:00:00 - 02/01/2017 17:00:00
01/01/2017 03:00:00 - 03/01/2017 20:00:00
02/01/2017 08:00:00 - 04/01/2017 23:00:00
```

I want the outcome to be:

```
01/01/2017 01:00:00 - 04/01/2017 23:00:00
```

I need it to do this over and over again until we have distinct ranges (non that overlap)

Comment: (using MySql )that was done in error mate sorry.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: First of all, do you want to SELECT or DELETE ?? Please edit your question and add details.

Answer (score 0):

Use Min of start_date and Max of end_date that will give you the range GROUP BY key fields.